# Apache PDFBox segmented digits display not working

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, fillable

I have a fillable pdf in which i have a field IFSC code to be filled.

[image: This is the fillable field that needs to be filled in segments]

This is my code to fill the acroform

```
public String generatePreFilledMandateForm(PnachDownloadRequestDto request) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Constants.DATE_FORMAT_DD_MM_YYYY);
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
            String currentDate = dtf.format(now);
            String currentDateAdded10Years = dtf.format(now.plusYears(10));

            PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new ClassPathResource("templates/IDFCPnachForm.pdf").getInputStream());

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteData = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            PDAcroForm acroForm = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
            setTextField(acroForm,"date",currentDate,true);
            setTextField(acroForm,"rectangleWithBank",request.getBankName().toUpperCase(),false);
            setTextField(acroForm,"rectangleBankAcNumber",request.getAccountNumber(),true);
            setTextField(acroForm,"rectangleIfscMicr",request.getIfscCode(),true);
            setTextField(acroForm,"rectangleAmountWords",MoneyConverterDigitToWordsUtil.convertToWord(request.getAmountInRupees().toString()),false);
            setTextField(acroForm,"rectangleAmount",request.getAmountInRupees().toString() + "/-",false);
            setTextField(acroForm,"rectangleReference1",request.getLoanNo(),false);
            setTextField(acroForm,"rectangleMobileNo",request.getPhoneNo(),false);
            setTextField(acroForm,"rectanglePrimaryNameField",request.getCustomerName(),false);
            setTextField(acroForm,"fromDate",currentDate,true);
            setTextField(acroForm,"toDate",currentDateAdded10Years,true);

            acroForm.flatten();

            pdfDocument.save(byteArrayOutputStream);

            pdfDocument.close();
            String base64EncodedPdf = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

            return base64EncodedPdf;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in generatePreFilledMandateForm {}",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

private void setTextField(PDAcroForm acroForm, String fieldName, String value,boolean isCombField) throws IOException {
        if (value != null) {
            List<PDField> fields = acroForm.getFields();
            for (PDField field : fields) {
                if (field.getFullyQualifiedName().equals(fieldName)) {
                    if (isCombField) {
                        ((PDTextField) field).setComb(true);

                    }
                    field.setValue(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But post filling and flattening. The response pdf doesn't have proper comb structure. PFB Response.

[image]

Also,
I am using Apache PDFBox 2.0.29.

Expected form:
[image]

Comment: @TilmanHausherr changing the version to 2.0.29 didn't help either.

Comment: Please share the PDF. If you can't share the PDF, try to reproduce the problem with a non confidential document and share that one. We do support comb fields. Btw setTextField() is too complex, you can access the field directly with `acroform.getField(name)`.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11u_gQQbshb1ARFVMU1VMZDarKT9nhnUV/view?usp=sharing.
@TilmanHausherr, Please find above the fillable pdf document. Also, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I had a look... the glyphs look better on my machine. But I think what you're complaining about is that you're missing the combs. The PDF specification doesn't mention these, although I see that Adobe does them. Maybe it didn't at the time this was written.

Comment: Here's how it looks: https://imgur.com/a/3ZQabae

Comment: Figured out that it was an issue with the pdf. Flattened the pdf and recreated the form fields using adobe acrobat. Now it is working just fine. Thanks @KJ & TilmanHausherr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with the pdf i was using. Flattening the pdf and then recreating the form fields using adobe acrobat made it work.

Also, a smaller optimisation in setTextField method(suggested by @TilmanHausherr)

```
private void setTextField(PDAcroForm acroForm, String fieldName, String value,boolean isCombField) throws IOException {
    if (value != null) {
        acroForm.getField(fieldName).setValue(value);
        if(isCombField) {
            ((PDTextField)acroForm.getField(fieldName)).setComb(true);
        }
    }
}
```